# Major IE8 positioning issues part 2

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a social network for the cystic fibrosis community. There is a section (s) where you can leave comments, and reply to the comments. This is generated with html,css,and jquery and works amazingly on FF,Safari, and Chrome, as you can guess, it has major quirks on IE8.

It works as it should when the comment is small, or there are not other replies underneath a existing comment. When the comment is big or there are other replies under the comment, it juts off to the left out of line, as opposed to sitting under the comment and above the existing replies as it should.

I have spent 5 hours trying to figure this out today and have a deadline at the end of the day. I am starting to panic because over 50% of our users are on IE

If you can help. a good profile to test this on is:

http://www.cysticlife.org/Profile_future.php?id=3

This is a private site, so you are more then welcome to sign in when prompted with my email and pw and go to the above link

email:
cherabcore@yahoo.com

pw:
RiffRock08

If you think you know what the problem is, and can help, please let me know if you need any code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of cross browser issues can be tracked down by validating your html and css code using an online validation service and then using something like firebug or the IE dev toolbar to try to track down the problem. There's unfortunately no magic solution for this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

One option that might work is http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

I haven't really looked much into this, but it's supposed to make the browser behave like a standards-compliant browser.

If you include the file like follows:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

it'll make an IE browser think it's IE9, which is more standards-compliant. I'm not saying it'll fix everything, but it might be worth looking into..

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into more, but that did not do anything.

Comment: Yeah, I really appreciate the effort though :) Have a good one!